# Why do I get a version mismatch during composer install for an outdated php version even though correct php version is installed?

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7

Given the very base `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "kopernikus/fizzbuzz",
  "description": "FizzBuzz!",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.5"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Philipp Kretzschmar",
      "email": "philipp.kretzschmar@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I run:

```
$ composer install
```

I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.0 but your PHP version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.6.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.4 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.3 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.2 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.8 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.7 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.6 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.5 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.4 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.3 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.2 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.4.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.5 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.4 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.3 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.2 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.9 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.8 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.7 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.6 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.5 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.4 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.3 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.2 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.12 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.11 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.10 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.0 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.7 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.6 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.5 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.4 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.3 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.2 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.1.0 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.9 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.8 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.7 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.6 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.5 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.4 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.3 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.2 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.10 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.1 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.0 requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.4 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu_bc.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
```

I am highley confused since:

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2017 20:09:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

I also checked the composer script, it has defined:

```
$ which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer

$ head -n 1 /usr/local/bin/composer
#!/usr/bin/env php

$ /usr/bin/env php
PHP 7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2017 20:09:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Even `diagnose` gives no cause to alarm:

```
$ composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.6.1
PHP version: 7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php7.0
```

Why does composer think I am running php@5.5 even though I only have php@7 installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your composer config, you have overwritten your [platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) settings.

This becomes apparent by the log line:

```
   - phpunit/phpunit 5.5.4 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

The important bit:

```
your PHP version (7...) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.5)
```

Also, you can see if it is set via:

```
$ composer config platform.php
5.5
```

It's useful for build machines so that composer can install dependencies on machines running different php versions. Yet it should not have persisted on my development machine.

I set the platform to 5.5 in the past to still be able to `composer install` a php5 project under php7 even though `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` would suffice or one could set the platform config on a project level as well. I had it in the global config though:

```
$ jq . ~/.composer/config.json 
{
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "5.5"
    }
  }
}
```

On newer composer version the config bay be part of the:

```
jq . ~/.config/composer/composer.json 
{
  "require": {
    "hirak/prestissimo": "^0.3.7"
  },
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "5.5"
    }
  }
}
```

I might also exist within your project's `composer.json`.

I had to remove the platform config *and* had to `composer update` the project's `composer.lock` as well. Only removing the config did not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As part of a new project I did a git checkout then `composer install` which gave me the error mentioned. Mine was

```
composer install

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.1.0 but your PHP version (7.0.18; Package overridden via config.platform (actual: 7.2.21)) does not satisfy that requirement.
...
```

This turned out to a coworker checked in `composer.lock` file which had

```
    "platform-overrides": {
        "php": "7.0.18"
```

#### Cause

When doing [`composer install`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i) composer uses the `composer.lock` file only. This is logical if one knows but very confusion for the few times one encounter such event.