# Laravel app stopped working after run older version app in new version laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

Getting This Error When run older version app in new version laravel framework

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS>php artisan serve

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass(
) is deprecated in C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\
src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788
Stack trace:

#0 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(788): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->h
andleError(8192, 'Method Reflecti...', 'C:\\Users\\User\\D...', 788)

#1 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(757): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies
(Array)

#2 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Excepti
ons\\...')

#3 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(564): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Excep
tions\\...', Array)

#4 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\F
oundation\Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->makeWith('App\\E
xceptions\\...', Array)
#5 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(248): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->makeWith('App\\E
xceptions\\...', Array)

#6 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(726): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Containe
r\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)

#7 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closur
e))
#8 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate
\\Cont...')
#9 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\F
oundation\Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate
\\Cont...')
#10 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\
Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(159): Illuminate\Foundation\Applicatio
n->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')

#11 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\
Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(101): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\
HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler()
#12 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\
Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\H
andleExceptions->renderForConsole(Object(ErrorException))
#13 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handl
eException(Object(ErrorException))
#14 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Ill
uminate\Container\Container.php on line 788
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass(
) is deprecated in C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\
src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(788): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->h
andleError(8192, 'Method Reflecti...', 'C:\\Users\\User\\D...', 788)
#1 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(757): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies
(Array)
#2 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Excepti
ons\\...')

#3 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(564): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Excep
tions\\...', Array)

#4 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\F
oundation\Application.php(709): Illuminate\Container\Container->makeWith('App\\E
xceptions\\...', Array)

#5 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(248): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->makeWith('App\\E
xceptions\\...', Array)

#6 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(726): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Containe
r\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)

#7 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closur
e))
#8 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\C
ontainer\Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate
\\Cont...')
#9 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\F
oundation\Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate
\\Cont...')
#10 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\
Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(159): Illuminate\Foundation\Applicatio
n->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#11 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\
Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(101): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\
HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler()
#12 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\
Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\H
andleExceptions->renderForConsole(Object(ErrorException))
#13 C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\
Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(123): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\
HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(ErrorException))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handl
eShutdown()
#15 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\User\Desktop\jkcarries\TMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Ill
uminate\Container\Container.php on line 788
```

```
Here my composer.json file
```

```
{
    
"name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
     },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
     },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
  }
```

my php version is 8.0.1 and  laravel framework version is 8.38.0
,I tried to reinstall composer and also  change  php version   to 8.0.1 ,  but still nothing changed ,I dont know whats going on .. how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: From your composer.json it is obvious that it is using Laravel version 5.4.*.

You can find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218631/laravel-app-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-php-8) useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel app stopped working after upgrading to php 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218631/laravel-app-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-php-8)

Comment: after updating composer getting error

Comment: Can you clarify what error are you getting after updating composer?

Comment: Error : phpunit/phpunit[5.7.0, ..., 5.7.27] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.0, ..., 5.7.27].

Comment: I am not completely sure how to solve this problem but I think 1st answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100614/why-do-i-get-a-version-mismatch-during-composer-install-for-an-outdated-php-vers) question will be useful

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233686/discussion-between-gopalkrish-and-ali-abbasov).